# Hide scrollbar in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

In our application for UI we are using JSF or Prime faces for that.
We would like to hide the scrollbar for our application, but we are struggling to achieve this in Internet Explorer (We are using IE7).

Is there any way to prevent for displaying the scroll bar in Internet explorer?
I tried to put `overflow: hidden;` in CSS,but it's not working.

I have tried nearly every node in the DOM and set `width`/`height` to `100%`, with `margin: 0px`, `padding: 0px`. Seems to work great in Firefox, but it doesn't work in IE7?

Comment: What to look and where to look?

Comment: If you ask about the scroll bar on the BODY element, see the response from __Fraser__ for IE. If not - make the question more precise.

Comment: IE6? [http://www.ie6countdown.com/](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)

Comment: @dov.amir....please provide any solution bcoz i dnt have good knowledge abt that.

Answer (score 108):

In case of anyone still needs a solution, this one worked for me:

```
.container{
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This change allows scroll on the container and hides the bars on IE.

If on the other hand you want to hide it and show it again once the user scroll again you can use.

```
.container {
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

In case you want to hide it completely (the scrollbar) not only from a specific container you can use:

```
    body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;  }
```

**Tested** on IE 10 && 11.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx)

Comment: You might not need this any more now that edge has decided to is going to adopt chromium.  https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MSEdge/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 21):

Hard to say without seeing the code! Saying that, You could try use using the "Extended Attributes" that Microsoft introduced for Internet Explorer.

```
<body scroll="no">
```

**EDIT:**

You could also try setting the overflow property of the html page in CSS like so.

```
html, body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: @FFraser....i tested it but its not working,still display the scrollbar.do you any other solution?

Comment: @BalusC...please see this issue.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `overflow:hidden` will not work for you unless you have a defined height.

Comment: @Dalal +1 - Good point - the OP has posted no code so I am just throwing out possibilities...

Comment: As far as I know, the second one does not help, the scrollbar is still shown but disabled.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question at all. It removes scrolling entirely not hiding the scroll bar.

Comment: @BenRacicot -  <element scroll="no"> does  in IE7,  where element is the element with the scrollbar you are trying to hide, which is what the OP was asking about. Why are you still using IE7?

Answer (score 10):

This CSS works for me both in Chrome and IE 10:

```
/* Oculta la scroll-bar pero sigue permitiendo hacer scroll con el mouse */
    body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;  }
    html, body { -ms-overflow-style: none; overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: This is the true answer to the question but still only addresses ie10+

Answer (score 2):

You may use this code implement it into body --

```
body { overflow-x:hidden; }
```

If not by that look into the layout and see if any container have a untoward width of something which is making the layout stretch a bit...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure IE is not in compatibility mode before you beat yourself up while trying `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 2):

use

```
.classname {
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

This automatically hides the scollbar but shows it again when scrolling

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style

Answer (score -1):

I cannot provide plain CSS solution, but if you use jQuery, it is easy to set the computed width and height to the body this way:

```
$("body").css({"width": body.width()+"px", "height": body.height()+"px"})
```

and then

```
$("body").css({"overflow": "hidden"});
```

worked also in IE (at least in IE9+). My goal was to make page not scrollable temporarily (when custom dialog with own scrolling capability was shown). And when custom dialog was closed, I reset the body style attribute to its previous state (to remove the computed body width and height).