# overflow-x: hidden in IE11 creates vertical scrollbar

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

In Chrome, I have a property of overflow-x: hidden on the td's of a table.  When the cell's contents exceeds the cell, the rest of the contents are hidden.  When I go to test this in IE11, the contents of the are hidden; however, there is a nasty vertical scrollbar that appears and I'm not sure why.  Here is what it looks like:

[image]

If I uncheck that property in dev tools, then the vertical scrollbar goes away, however, the contents overflow into the row. Is there some way to resolve this?

Comment: try this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242385/hide-scrollbar-in-ie

Comment: Neither of those suggestions worked.

Comment: Did you try specifying an overflow-y: hidden at the same time ?

Comment: Yes.  I did try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

well since you want hide the cell's contents when this exceeds the cell space you should try text-overflow something like:

```
<table class="custom">
  <tr>
    <td>
      long long long long lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng
    </td> 
        <td>
      long long long long lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng
    </td> 
        <td>
      long long long long lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng
    </td> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      long long long long lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng
    </td> 
        <td>
      long long long long lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng
    </td> 
        <td>
      long long long long lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng
    </td> 
  </tr>
</talble>
```

and the css:

```
.custom td {
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)