# Remove the scrollbar in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a layout page which I use in every pages. Among these Cshtml pages, I need to remove scroll bar from some. I gave a code, which is working fine in google chrome, but failing in internet explorer. Can any one help me?
Thanks in advance.My code is below

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style = 'overflow: hidden';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scrollbar in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242385/hide-scrollbar-in-ie)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has their own property for their browsers. Use this CSS property:

```
-ms-overflow-style: none;
```

Read more about it [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the html element that is producing the scrollbar in IE. Try this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style = 'overflow: hidden';
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style = 'overflow: hidden';
```

I usually handle this with CSS like this:

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```